# EOQ Inventory Model Diagram in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Has anyone done the EOQ inventory model diagram using tikz? Can anyone please share the code for it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. Could you please post some examples of what you want to get and show some code effort?

Comment: What is an EOQ inventory model diagram? Images I could find just look like some random (?) functions in a coordinate system. Maybe you can try to have a go yourself first and ask specifically when a problem comes up you can't solve. You will find many resources on this site and the internet in general to get started with `pgfplots` or `tikz`.

Comment: Do you mean, like the one appearing here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_order_quantity

Answer (score 1):

If the figure to be produced is like this one (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_order_quantity)):

[image: EOQ]

This can be done with `pgfplots`, if you know the equations of those curves. To get started:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [mark=none,red,thick,samples=250, domain=0:20] {4*x}; 
    \addplot [mark=none,blue,thick,samples=250, domain=1.6:20] {150/exp(sqrt(x-1))}; 
    \addplot [mark=none,green!60!black,thick,samples=250, domain=1.6:20] {4*x+150/exp(sqrt(x-1))}; 
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: I wanted the saw structure used in the EOQ inventory level determination. I have written a code for it. Now I can't figure out how to put the code here. Thanks for the help.